# set src="id" iframe taking src by url.com/id

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

i'm tryng to set a src of an iframe taking the url from the toolbar address.

the address if composed by the domain + id (that is the same of the youtube id)

example
www.youtube.com/whatch=id

my domain is = www.domain.com/?id (the id is the same)

this my hypothetically script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var segment_str = window.location.pathname; 
   var segment_array = segment_str.split( '/' );
   var last_segment = segment_array[segment_array.length - 1];
   alert(last_segment);
   var iframe = document.getElementById("youtube");
   iframe.src = www.youtube.com/watch=last_segment;
   </script>
```

Comment: Maybe like this `iframe.src = "www.youtube.com/watch=" + last_segment;` ... note the added qoutes `"` and the `+`

Answer (score 1):

Maurizio Grasso!
@LGSon is almost right — you have to use quotes while setting iframe.src.
But if your domain is www.domain.com/?id (with question mark) you have to use `window.location.search` to get URL parameters instead of `window.location.pathname`, so your script becomes something like:

```
var id = window.location.search.slice(1); 
iframe.src = 'www.youtube.com/watch=' + id;
```